# My computer needs restart after it is idle for a while

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I am not sure what is exactly happening with my computer but this is fist time that I am noticing something like this.

- Whenever, I leave my laptop idle for few minutes, it goes in this Hibernate kind of mode(not exactly hibernate).
- Once it goes into that mode, problem is that it does not come back. If I touch the mouse pad or I press power button for a while.

Eventually, when I press the power button for a long time, it restarts it. I am not sure what is going on but I do not want to be restarting the machine every time I leave it for sometime.

Any ideas/solutions?

Thanks

Comment: No it is plugged in

Comment: There definitely can be compatibility issues between the hardware and hibernate.  You can see if there is BIOS update that needs done.  I have a workstation were hibernate issues were explicitly called out as an issue in the old BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

This often happens for a few reasons. One, your RST (intel rapid storage technology driver) is not up to date. When a PC comes out of hibernate, it needs to load the state that existed  beforehand from a file called "hiberfil.sys" back into system memory. Sometimes, there is a disconnect between the HDD on your PC because of this outdated RST driver. Second, it may happen due to an outdated iGPU or discrete GPU driver, make sure to update those.

However, a lot of times you may think you know what is happening and it's not actually occurring, so a few questions for you:

1. When you let it go, does it actually turn off? Or are there still LEDs flickering next to your battery symbol, etc ?
2. Is it going into hibernate, or sleep?
3. If you put your computer to sleep manually can you wake it up immediately after?